# Why is this algorithm O(n^2) in complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I know the big O complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2), but I cannot understand why.

```
int b=0;
for(int i=n; i>0; i--)
   for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
      b=b+5;
```

I know that the outer loop is O(n).  I know that the inner loop will run n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 times.  That is as far as I can get.  I am not sure where to go from there.

> My question is, can somebody explain why that algorithm is O(n^2) ?

Comment: n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = **?**

Comment: I think it must equal the total number of iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the total number of times the whole block of code would run

```
= n + (n-1) + ...+ 1 
= n * (n+1) / 2 
= O(n^2).
```

The other statements would take O(1), so their's would have no effect(not much role) on complexity(their's being a constant).

Comment: I see!  How did you set that sequence equal to n*(n+1)/2 ?

Comment: @OmarN - That is a formula ---> Sum of first n consecutive positive integers starting from 1 = 1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2.

Comment: Once you get to that formula, I understand how it becomes O(n^2), but I am not sure how that formula was derived.  Can you tell me how you came up with that formula?  Or if that is a topic for a new question, it might be better to post a new question for it.

Comment: @OmarN - You may post it, but, the answer is AP series. Here, starting term = 1, common difference = 1, last term = n, check the summation of AP series on the Web. You'll come to know.

Comment: Thank you!  Appreciate the help!

Comment: According to a well-known story, the formula was derived long ago by an elementary school student named Carl Friedrich Gauss when his math teacher wanted to take a break and asked the students to add up all the numbers from 1 to 100. Young Gauss realized that if he paired the lowest and highest numbers together (1 + 100, 2 + 99, etc.), each pair added up to 101 (which is n+1) and that there were 50 such pairs (which is n/2). So the sum from 1 to n is (n+1)(n/2). The teacher didn't get his break and Gauss went on to be a great mathematician,

Comment: @aro_tech - Thanks, nice to know that.

Answer (score 1):

outer loop | inner loop 
**i=n**        |   inner loop executes **n times**
**i=n-1**    |   inner loop executes **n-1 times** 
**i=n-2**    |   inner loop executes **n-2 times** 
.
 
.
.
**i=1**     | inner loop executes **1 time** and exits

now summing up total no of times inner loop executes : n + (n-1) +(n-2)+.....+1= n*(n+1)/2 = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: The same has OP mentioned in the question, you've added nothing new to OP's question.Consider either improving it, or otherwise delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically because there are n^2 more operations than in a single loop.